# Electric bicycle and an electric scooter

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical

Assuming that an electric bicycle and an electric scooter use the same motor and battery, which has more autonomy? that is, which makes more kilometers / miles per battery charge cycle? Obviously each vehicle logically has a different transmission and size of wheels.

Comment: I wonder what you are after? If you are making a point, this is the wrong forum. But could it also be seen as a continuum: what's the difference between a "bicycle" and "scooter", really? It may end up being human linguistics, and again the question is misplaced.

If you need an answer, as @kamran points out, you'll need to provide more info. Or is "bicycle, of course (since it's lighter) - but does it matter?" :) a good enough reply?

Comment: a scooter has much smaller wheels so I sense that for each turn of the engine covers a much smaller area, although I also believe that the engine needs less effort (I have no clear this relationship)

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that when I refer to scooter I mean an electric skateboard two wheels, like a Segway but with a handlebar

Comment: A Segway has two large wheels on the sides. Scooters have small wheels in front and back. Fundamentally different devices. In some parts of the world, the term "scooter" refers to a small motor cycle like a Vespa.

Answer (score 1):

Take a random electric bike and another electric motorbike, the base idea of designing them would be fairly similar: just a frame holding a battery and 2 wheels together. There is not that much difference between the two of them. Though I would say that the "bias" with electric motorbike is better (it is automatically assumed that it has a better range)

The transmission... I would say that have fairly similar layout, though the electric bike (or some of them) has the option for "pedalling" (use just like a normal bicycle), and again, the pedals can also be removed, practically making the electric bike an electric motorbike.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that when I refer to scooter I mean an electric skateboard two wheels, like a Segway but with a handlebar

Comment: Again, it depends a lot. Other than the fact that the electrical bike can be moved by pedals as if it is a normal bicycle, there is no major distinction between an electric scooter and an electric bike. The important part is other factors, most notably the battery and the over weight (passenger, dry weight and packages) of the vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the efficiency of the design, the wind drag, the quality of rejuvenative breaking.

The factors most influential in performance are not the form factor alone. Also both the scooter and electrical bike do not necessarily need a transmission as the torque can be adjusted electronically.